# Recursive multiline find/replace from command line

Tags: regex, shell, perl

I am trying to do a find and replace for import statements in js files. There are a few different variants that I need to be able to account for:

```
// default-import.js
import foo from 'bar-shared';

// named-import.js
import {Foo} from 'bar-shared/foo';

// type-import.js
import type {FooType} from 'bar-shared/foo';

// multiline-import.js
import {
  Foo,
  reduceFoo,
} from 'bar-shared/foo';

// multiline-with-type-import.js
import {
  Foo,
  reduceFoo,
  type FooType,
} from 'bar-shared/foo';

// multiple-import.js
import foo from 'bar-shared';
import {Foo} from 'bar-shared/foo';
import {
  Baz
  reduceBaz
} from 'bar-shared/baz';
```

My end goal is to replace `bar-shared` with `@bar/core`. But the limitations are:
- I don't know what the specific imports are
- An import statement can be over multiple lines
- There can be multiple import statements for `bar-shared` in a single file

I have gotten reasonably close on with the following:

```
find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec \
  perl -0777 -p -i -e "s/^import ([\s\S]*?) from 'bar-shared(.*)'/import \1 from '\@bar\/core\2'/gms" {} +
```

That script doesn't seem to be finding all of the instances though. Specifically the final example type, with more than one import statement in the file, seems to be the real problem.

Comment: Something like [**`import(?:(?!from).)*(?:{[^{}]+})?\s*from\s*'\Kbar-shared`**](https://regexr.com/3j9vt) ?

Comment: in addition to removing `^`  you have to change `(.*)` to `(.*?)`. You want to capture only up to the next `'`. Otherwise it would match the rest of the line in the first go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you always need to match from `import` to the first `from 'bar-shared'`. Then

```
perl -i -0777 -wpe's{import.*?from\s+\x27\Kbar\-shared}{\@bar/core}gs'
```

The `\x27` is the [hexadecimal escape](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Character-Escapes) for the single quote (27). The `/s` modifier makes `.` match newlines, too, which is all you need to process this multiline string in this way. The `\K` discards all previous matches so they need not be captured and replaced.

Tested on your example but I am not sure what may appear inside `import` blocks in JS.